# Table View update using PartialView when search function works

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I want original table view list update without page refreshing using partial view

My Main View Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       IEnumerable<ClassFile> listdata = ...
       return View(listdata);
    }
```

View Page

```
      @model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Model.ClassFile>
      @{
           ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
           Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
       } 
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="sampledata">
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ID)</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

In `_Layout` page I have following popup to search and ajax call to update above view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")        
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="content-page">

            <div class="content">
                <div class="container">
                    RenderBody()
                <footer class="">                        
                </footer>
            </div> 
        </div>

    <div id="panel-modal">
           <div class="form-group"> 
           <input type="text" id="searchstring">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group"> 
            <button id="btnSearch" type="button" class="ss">Search</button>
         </div>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {            

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/SampleSearch",
                data: { searchtext: $('#searchstring').val()},
                dataType: "html",
                Success: function (response)
                {
                    alert("Success");
                   $('#sampledata').html(response);                        

                },
                error: function ()
                {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
            return false

        });
    });
</script>
```

for above search function I have following method in Same Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SampleSearch(string searchstring)
    {
        IEnumerable<ClassFile> listsearchData = ...
        return PartialView("Index", listsearchData );            
    }
```

But here Initial Table loading working fine, but then when I search through popup and click btnSearch button its not updating index page, when I debug I can see values getting in SampleSearch method, there no error occurring also

Comment: Why returning Index page as partial view response since it declared as a view page? Partial views should use `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.RenderPartial` to render them. If your action method returns html response to render in page body, use @Html.Raw instead.

Comment: Your `Index.cshtml` view contains the table, so remove the `id="sampledata"` from the `<tbody>` element and in your layout add `<div id="sampledata"></div>` for the placeholder. Alternatively create a separate partial view that renders only the `<tbody>` element

Comment: All properties of the `$.ajax` settings object start with a lowercase letter, yet you seem to be using `Success: ...`

Comment: I preferred using separate partial view file since it has `SampleSearch` action method which returns a partial view. Since JS is case sensitive by nature, `Success` property possibly doesn't match when finding for `success` one.

Comment: @StephenMuecke where should I add `<div id="sampledata"></div>` in `_Layout` page

Comment: @PeterB Okay thanks Noted :) now I can see alert message

Comment: Anywhere you want, but you really should be doing this by creating a separate partial view named (say) `_SampleSearch.cshtml` which is simply `@model IEnumerable<ClassFile> @foreach (var item in Model){ <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ID)</td></tr>}` and in the controller `return View("_SampleSearch", listsearchData);` and then in the `Index` view, replace your `foreach` loop with `@Html.Partial("_SampleSearch")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke , but when I replace that with `foreach loop with @Html.Partial("_SampleSearch")` How to allow to load initial data set ?

Comment: Because `@Html.Partial("_SampleSearch")` passes the model in the `Index` method (which is `IEnumerable<ClassFile>`) to the partial view which then generates the html and adds it to the Index view

Comment: @StephenMuecke does this renderbody should be stay like this  `<div class="container">
                        <div id="stationdata">@RenderBody()</div>
                       
                    </div>`

Comment: @kez, Sorry, but where is `<div class="container">`? (I cant see that in your question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry I just added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125315/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the ajax code to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SampleSearch", "Home")', // don't hard code url's
    data: { searchtext: $('#searchstring').val()},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) // lowercase (not Success)
    {
       $('.container').html(response);                        
    },
    ....
});
```

The main issue is that `Success` (capital S) is not an ajax option and it needs to be lowercase `success`. The second issue is that your `Index.cshtml` view contains a table and your current selector is its `<tbody>` element, so you trying to render a `<table>` within a`<tbody>` which would be invalid. Change the selector to use the `<div>` element that encloses the table.

As an alternative, you can create a partial view that renders only the table rows (say `_SampleSearch.cshtml`)

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Model.ClassFile>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ID)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

and change the `Index.cshtml` view to remove the `@foreach (var item in Model) { ... }` loop and replace it with `@Html.Partial("_SampleSearch")` (or `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_SampleSearch"); }`), and finally change the controller method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SampleSearch(string searchstring)
{
    IEnumerable<ClassFile> listsearchData = ...
    return PartialView("_SampleSearch", listsearchData );            
}
```